# How to reference a specific cell location within a changing table

Tags: vba, excel

I am not sure how, if at all, this can be done. Basically I have a report that is generated from SalesForce for some co-workers. It exports to Excel in this nice little table. Depending on their team, they filter the results and then filter the month (fiscal year in this case).

What I want to do is have text populate at the top which is based on the text that is in the first cell in the column C (not including header row of course) when they filter. How do I go about referencing the spot where C4 is currently when they select Team "White-1" and Fiscal Year "Aug"? That cell will become hidden and I will need to pull the data from C6 which HAPPENS to be in the location that C4 was just in before being hidden.

Here is an image of the report in Excel as well as the "location" that I want to reference no matter the filtering that the employee does:

[Report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5X9W0.png)

I assume VBA will be needed. Preferably I want to generate the text in A1

Comment: Index will work even if Rows are hidden but you have to write the Formula in a cell that will not be hidden

Comment: You can use `=C4` in A1 or `=INDEX(C4:C100,1)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are ok with adding a "Helper Column" you can do the following to get the results you are wanting:

Add a column between B and C Give it a header of some kind I used "Helper". Then in this new Column use use the formula `=Row()` to generate a number for each row.

You can hide this column now if you want.

Then in whichever cell you want the answer you seek enter the following formula:

```
=Vlookup(Aggregate(5,5,C:C),C:D,2,false)
```

Now you can filter all you want and you should get the result you wanted.

Comment: Sure thing. Glad I could help.